# Full width hr element in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and I wonder how can we give an element a full width of the screen? for example I have an `<hr>`element that I want it width to be take the full screen.

I notice that `row` is taking -15px `margin-left` and `margin-right`, how can we remove that margin without affecting other rows in the website?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shadeed9/pwvg6o7n/ (See full screen for better view)

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply have to put it out of the container.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- STUFF -->
  </div>
</div>
<hr> <!----- here -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- STUFF -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, can you please update the jsfiddle with your answer?

Comment: Well, it works for me. Bootstrap is not included in your JSFiddle so I don't see the point in updated it.